# how to get the key-value style information from the following string by using python's re module

Tags: python, regex

we have a string like this:

```
2016-11-10 00:00:44,766 INFO [com.server.log.Log] - <Login Success. userInfo:  userID = 140803;appID = 3;channelID = 309;channelUserID = 76ab5a49ea40477f9623074d0d5e0227;userName = 1477806062675.ios.test;channelUserName = l379192229;createTime = 2016-10-30 13:41:02.0;loginTime = 1478707244762;userIP = 61.158.146.157;IMEI = FB7FE841-9E54-4421-86E0-1ED625068C57;newUser = false>
```

and now I want to extract the key-value information from the string by using python's re module.

and as a result, it should be a dict : `{'userID': 140803, 'channelid':309...}`

Comment: Have you made any attempt so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import re

string = """
2016-11-10 00:00:44,766 INFO [com.server.log.Log] - <Login Success. userInfo:  userID = 140803;appID = 3;channelID = 309;channelUserID = 76ab5a49ea40477f9623074d0d5e0227;userName = 1477806062675.ios.test;channelUserName = l379192229;createTime = 2016-10-30 13:41:02.0;loginTime = 1478707244762;userIP = 61.158.146.157;IMEI = FB7FE841-9E54-4421-86E0-1ED625068C57;newUser = false>
"""

rx = re.compile(r'(?P<key>\w+)[ ]*=[ ]*(?P<value>[^;]+)')

result = dict()
for m in rx.finditer(string):
    result[m.group('key')] = m.group('value')
print(result)
# {'userName': '1477806062675.ios.test', 'channelUserName': 'l379192229', 'channelID': '309', 'userID': '140803', 'loginTime': '1478707244762', 'IMEI': 'FB7FE841-9E54-4421-86E0-1ED625068C57', 'appID': '3', 'userIP': '61.158.146.157', 'channelUserID': '76ab5a49ea40477f9623074d0d5e0227', 'newUser': 'false>\n', 'createTime': '2016-10-30 13:41:02.0'}
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/B4KcaD).

Comment: I use this pattern to get it: __login_success_pattern = '.*userInfo:\s\s(.*?)\s=\s(.*?)(?=;)|.*?;(.*?)\s=\s(.*?)(?=[;|>])'

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like so:

```
import re

a = """2016-11-10 00:00:44,766 INFO [com.server.log.Log] - <Login Success. userInfo:  userID = 140803;appID = 3;channelID = 309;channelUserID = 76ab5a49ea40477f9623074d0d5e0227;userName = 1477806062675.ios.test;channelUserName = l379192229;createTime = 2016-10-30 13:41:02.0;loginTime = 1478707244762;userIP = 61.158.146.157;IMEI = FB7FE841-9E54-4421-86E0-1ED625068C57;newUser = false>"""
a = [re.split('\s*=\s*',b) for b in re.findall(r'(?:userInfo:\s*)(.*)', a)[0].split(';')]
d = dict(a)
d
```

Output:

```
{'IMEI': 'FB7FE841-9E54-4421-86E0-1ED625068C57',
 'appID': '3',
 'channelID': '309',
 'channelUserID': '76ab5a49ea40477f9623074d0d5e0227',
 'channelUserName': 'l379192229',
 'createTime': '2016-10-30 13:41:02.0',
 'loginTime': '1478707244762',
 'newUser': 'false>',
 'userID': '140803',
 'userIP': '61.158.146.157',
 'userName': '1477806062675.ios.test'}
```

Steps:

1. Select everything after `userInfo:`
2. Split on `;`
3. Loop through the list in step2 and split on \s*=\s*.
4. Make a dictionary from the list of lists from step3